# Insert url value in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following string to get items from my database:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracking WHERE track_id = '123' ");
```

I want to get the `123` from the url using a process similar to `echo $_GET['id'];` so when the url is "http://example.com/?id=456" the string will apear as below:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracking WHERE track_id = '456' ");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before you actually use any of the suggested solutions, please read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114) as none of them addressed it.

Comment: Don't use mysql queries, they are deprecated. Use mysqli instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already proposed...

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracking WHERE track_id = '<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>' ");
```

or (since you are probably already in php)...

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracking WHERE track_id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "' ");
```

Comment: wow, didn't think it was that simple, well don't I look like a huge idiot lol... Thank you soo much for your help!

Comment: I'd sanitize the input before doing the search though @user3040416

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracking WHERE track_id = '".$_GET['id']."' ");

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracking WHERE track_id = '".$_GET['id']."' ");

Answer (score 0):

That'd be a possible approach.
Remember that mysql functions are deprecated (use  [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) instead) and don't forget to sanitize your input.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($id);

mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM tracking WHERE track_id = '".$id."' ");
```